# HTML table with mcustomscrollbar and fixed column header

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, html-table, mcustomscrollbar

I have created a table with scrollbar in which header is fixed while scrolling y and header is scrolling while scrolling table x. Here is my code.

```js
$(function () {
 $('table').on('scroll', function () {
  $("table > *").width($("table").width() + $("table").scrollLeft());
  });
});
```

```css
html {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height: 25px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
}
thead {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}
tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 140px;
}
td, th {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    border: dashed 1px lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
            <th>Column 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But problem is that I can't implement this functionality with mcustomscrollbar. And I want this functionality of scrolling with mcustomscrollbar or with any other attractive CSS on scrollbar which can not be affected by browser. If anyone knows the solution of this problem, then answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

add this in your script -

```
$(".dataTables_scrollBody").mCustomScrollbar({  // custom scroll bar plugin
theme:"minimal-dark",  // custom scroll theme set
axis: "yx",     // custom scroll ver,hor scroll
callbacks: {    // callback for thead,tbody scroll
whileScrolling: function() {
$(".dataTables_scrollHead").scrollLeft(this.mcs.left *-1);
},
},
});
```

Hope, It helps. Need more info check this also -

http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/callbacks_example.html

Answer (score 1):

Make a table like this

```
<div class="graphData" data-mcs-axis="x">
    <table class="fixed_headers">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>data1</th><th>data2</th><th>data3</th></tr>   
        </thead>
        <tbody >
            <tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td></tr>
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Add script before `</body>`

```
$(window).load(function(){

  $("table.fixed_headers tbody").mCustomScrollbar({
    mouseWheel:{ preventDefault: true },
    autoExpandScrollbar:true
  });

  $(".graphData").mCustomScrollbar({
            scrollbarPosition:"outside"
  });
});
```

this script will add `x` scroll to header and `xy` scroll to `tbody`

Answer (score 0):

Check following way you can use `mCustomScrollbar`. Use `$("tbody").mCustomScrollbar({`

```js
$(function () {
 $('table').on('scroll', function () {
  $("table > *").width($("table").width() + $("table").scrollLeft());
  });

  $("tbody").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme:"light-3",
    scrollButtons:{
      enable:false
    },
    mouseWheel:{ preventDefault: true },
    scrollbarPosition: 'inside',
    autoExpandScrollbar:true,
    theme: 'dark',
     axis:"yx",
                setWidth: "auto"
  });

});
```

```css
html {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height: 25px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
thead {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}
tbody {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 140px;
}

td, th {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    border: dashed 1px lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/dragospaulpop/cdnjs/master/ajax/libs/jQuery.custom.content.scroller/3.1.11/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dragospaulpop/cdnjs/master/ajax/libs/jQuery.custom.content.scroller/3.1.11/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
            <th>Column 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's ok with header while scrolling vertical. But while scrolling x, header should be aslo scrolled.